# Normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

The following is a question from an undergrad course in Galois theory:

> Find a normal closure $L$ of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

I know that normal extensions are splitting fields

Let: $X=\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}} \implies X^2=11+3\sqrt{13} \implies X^2-11=3\sqrt{13}\implies ({\frac{X^2-11}{3}})^2-13=0 $

Is this related to the splitting field?

Would the normal closure look something like: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}, \sqrt{13})$ since $\sqrt{11}, \sqrt{13} \notin \mathbb{Q}$? I am guessing not since we have the weird embedded square root

I have not really got my head aruond these questions so would very much appreciate your guidance

Comment: Is there something to the fact that $\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}=(3\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{26})/2$?

Comment: This would imply that the normal closure would be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{26})$, I believe... I was wondering how you knew this equality was the case? I would never have got there myself

Comment: I guess we should start from $\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}} \sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}} = \sqrt{121 - 117} = 2$, but as you I'm not sure what to do next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compute the zeros of $X^4-22 X^2+4=9\cdot ((\frac{X^2-11}3)^2-13)$. There is a general formula for equations of degree four which gives you
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}} && -\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}} && \sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}} && -\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}
\end{align*}
So the normal closure of $K$ is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}, \sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}})$.
Since
$$
\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}\cdot \sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}}=\sqrt{11^2-9\cdot 13}=\sqrt{4}=2,
$$
you can see that 
$$
\sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}}\in K
$$
and it follows that $K$ is normal already.

Comment: great thank you. I was wondering could you provide or link me to the equation of degree 4 that you used?

Comment: To be frank, I used a computer algebra system simply to confirm my suspicion. But the general method [is outlined on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution_methods). It's a bit tricky.

Comment: Fair enough. In my Galois course, we are expected to be able to use it so I will spend some time looking at this

Comment: didn't  you start from the polynomial $(X+a)(X-a)(X+\bar{a})(X-\bar{a})$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Suppose you are given a two-layer square root $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$.  If $a^2-b=r^2$ for some positive rational number $r$, then:

$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$

$x=(a+r)/2$

$y=(a-r)/2$